# How to add custom metadata in PDF file using react js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, filereader

I'm taking input as a PDF file and using javascript to add custom metadata, but I'm not getting a satisfactory result.
Below is a sample method code that I used to add custom metadata that is first converted to blob type and then added, but when we convert its blob data to base64 and download the file and check the properties, we cannot find it.

```
const blobToBase64 = (blob: any) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
    });

const updatePDFMetaData = (file: any, metadata: any) => {
    let convertBlobToBase64: any;
    const selectedFile = file;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(selectedFile);
    reader.onload = async (event:any) => {
      const fileBuffer: any = event?.target?.result;
      const blob: any = new Blob([fileBuffer], { type: selectedFile.type });
      Object.keys(metadata).forEach((key: any) => {
        blob[key] = metadata[key];
      });
      convertBlobToBase64 = await blobToBase64(blob);
      console.log("convertBlobToBase64", convertBlobToBase64);
    };
  };
```

Comment: Take a moment to think logically about your question. How can anyone answer this given the complete lack of detail you've provided?

Comment: I have added a sample code for it please check it once.